# Change color of smart tag

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, smart-tags

Smart tags are almost impossible to see when using the dark theme on visual studio 2012. how do i change the color of smart tags.

Going to tools>options>environment>fonts and colors>smart tags does not work

[image: smart tag to dark]

just to be clear, in the image above, i am talking about the small blue box under the 't', not the red squiggly line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed it as a problem and has added this defect to their backlog:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/796055/extremely-hard-to-see-smart-tag-when-using-dark-theme

Comment: link is dead and problem persists

Answer (score 1):

It's in **Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors**:

- Show settings for: *Text Editor*
- Display Items: **Compiler Error**

You can change the *Item Foreground* property to get the color of the squiggly to change.

Comment: i am referring to that small blue box under the 't' not the red squiggly line

Comment: Oh. I don't think there's an option for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have visual studio in front of me,  but I believe that is under the text editor options.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember that color is hard-coded to a constant, so you can't change it. Use Ctrl + . to invoke smart tags when there is one on the screen, it is much easier than hunting it down via the mouse.

Comment: the problem is not clicking it with the mouse, rather seeing it in the first place

Comment: Yep, sorry :( if you are really passionate about this, you can fairly easily make an extension for the editor to show you an alternative view when a smart tag is present (something on the margin perhaps, or an adornment on the editor). You would have to listen for tag changes of type SmartTag and when they appear, draw something on the view. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee334190.aspx

Comment: I think 2013 is coming out soon, maybe the big new feature is modifying the smart tag.